# How to find the sum of values with the same variable in 2d list python, with using only list comprehension?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, list-comprehension

Say that I have a list of lists:

```
list_of_lists = [['5464', 49.96], ['5464', 99.91], ['5464', 99.91], ['7733', 208.89], ['8274', 233.82], ['8732', 93.93], ['88112', 274.89], ['88112', 199.75], ['9744', 404.55], ['9744', 404.55]]
```

How should I use list comprehension to find the total sum of each variable?

```
E.g. sum_of_lists = [['5464', 249.78],['7733',208.89],['8274',233.82],['8732',93.93],['88112',474.64],['9744', 809.1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to collect the sublists by the first element. Then `sum` the second element of the sublists in each group.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> [[k, sum(i[1] for i in g)] for k, g in groupby(list_of_lists, key=lambda i: i[0])]
[['5464', 249.78], ['7733', 208.89], ['8274', 233.82], ['8732', 93.93], ['88112', 474.64], ['9744', 809.1]]
```

Note that `groupby` assumes the groups are already sorted/contiguous, so if that is not already the case, you'd need to `sort` your list first using that same `key`.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is sorted by the first element, You could use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

list_of_lists = [['5464', 49.96], ['5464', 99.91], ['5464', 99.91], ['7733', 208.89], ['8274', 233.82], ['8732', 93.93],
                 ['88112', 274.89], ['88112', 199.75], ['9744', 404.55], ['9744', 404.55]]

res = [[key, sum(v for _, v in group)] for key, group in groupby(list_of_lists, key=itemgetter(0))]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['5464', 249.78], ['7733', 208.89], ['8274', 233.82], ['8732', 93.93], ['88112', 474.64], ['9744', 809.1]]
```

As an alternative, for general inputs, you could use the following approach:

```
od = OrderedDict()
for key, value in list_of_lists:
    if key in od:
        od[key] = od[key] + value
    else:
        od[key] = value

res = list(od.items())
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[('5464', 249.78), ('7733', 208.89), ('8274', 233.82), ('8732', 93.93), ('88112', 474.64), ('9744', 809.1)]
```

Note that for Python 3.6+ you can use a regular *dict*, instead of an *OrderedDict*.

Finally this two approaches are `O(n)`, linear time, and will scale better for larger inputs.